# Error in Go's slices exercise

Tags: go, arguments

I'm trying to solve the slices exercise. My current solution is

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    picture := make([][]uint8, dy)

    x := dx

    for iy := 0; iy < dy; iy++ {
        picture[iy] = make([]uint8, dx)

        for ix := 0; ix < dx; ix++ {
            x = (x+dy)/2
            picture[iy][ix] = uint8(x)
        }
    }

    return picture
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic(1,2))
}
```

But I'm getting the following error

> tmp/sandbox931798243/main.go:23: cannot use Pic(1, 2) (type [][]uint8)
>   as type func(int, int) [][]uint8 in argument to pic.Show

What am I doing wrong? Might that be a bug with the sandbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pic.Show` takes a single argument of type `func(int, int) [][]uint8` - you need to pass it a function. You're passing the *result of executing* a `func(int, int) [][]uint8`, i.e. a `[][]uint8`. What you want would be:

```
pic.Show(Pic)
```

Passing in your function `Pic` itself, which meets the requirements.

Comment: Damn, thank you! You should read the error message before asking... thanks again!

Comment: Error messages usually have the answer, but it's not always clear what they're telling you...

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the source to pc.Show here:
https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tour/+/master:pic/pic.go

pic.Show takes your function as a parameter, then it calls the function with values 256, 256